# Is REST only adequate for applications with human-computer interaction?

Tags: rest, architecture, restful-architecture, hateoas

I am fairly new to building applications using the RESTful architecture. As a matter of fact, all I have done so far is categorized as [Level 2 REST](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) by Leonard Richardson and that I know Fielding would [happily categorize](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) as Non-RESTful.

I have spent hours trying to understand HATEOAS and how to reach level 4. And I see it more clearly now. I conceptualize the application as a series of state transitions, and the resources will dynamically provide links with information on how to move from one state to another.

But everything related to HATEOAS seem to be inherent of a human-computer interaction. I mean, even when the resources provide the links that enable the application user to move to the next state, it is ultimately the user the one that drives the application from one state to the other by causing the use of of the provided links.

But how are things supposed to work when we are dealing with computer-to-computer interaction? After all when it comes to service-orientation the idea of service composition is key, and we cannot naively assume that the client is always going to be a human being? Many services are designed to be consumed by non-human users, and some interactions/orchestrations might be fairly complex, the type of things that are typically modeled with things like BPM, or BPEL.

Is REST and particularly HATEOAS only usable in applications that imply human intervention and if not how is this supposed to work otherwise?

I am getting this vibe that REST is only good for certain type of solutions and inadequate for others, but literature out there has failed to explain those inadequacies and sell REST as the cure of all evil, but I just don't quite get how to use for proper service composition when humans are not the drivers.

I'd really appreciate any references or insights on this, because believe me I have two days straight reading all I have been able to find on this topic and I have not yet being able to reach any reasonable and well documented conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your client app can parse the response to get possible actions. In this case actual urls are obtained not from knowledge of the API, but upon calling the initial method (usually GET). All human-less.

Comment: You can obtain the endpoints dynamically when using SOAP as well but it results in some overhead compared to rest/hypermedia

Answer (score 1):

It sounds almost as if you're comparing SOA to REST/Hypermedia and fail to see that SOA is a strategy, for designing a complex system made out of other systems, while REST/Hypermedia is a software architecture style applying a bunch of constraints on client-server communication. The client, however, can be both a server or a human, it doesn't matter.

To use or not to use REST/Hypermedia is not something to bother with when outlining/designing service composition. It's a question that comes into play when trying to achieve syntactic interoperability. Many times it comes down to comparing REST to Soap and other technical details.

Comment: REST[ful architecture] is not a protocol, it is an application architecture.